# Plugin method declarations - can't make it work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've been struggling with exactly what the correct syntax is to make methods available on an object with a plugin.  Here's the basic framework:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://goo.gl/XQPhA"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $.test = function(el, options) {
        this.whiten = function() {
            $(this).css('background-color', options.bg);
        }
    };
    $.test.settings = {
        bg: 'white'
    };
    $.fn.test = function(options) {
        options = $.extend(options, $.test.settings);
        return this.each(function() {
            $.test(this, options);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#list').test().css('background-color', 'wheat');
    $('#go').click(function() {
        $('#list').whiten();
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<button id="go">whiten</button>
<ul id="list">
<li>Aloe</li>
<li>Bergamot</li>
<li>Calendula</li>
<li>Damiana</li>
<li>Elderflower</li>
<li>Feverfew</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

and I guess what I'm not sure about is how to make the function assignment.  `this` inside of `$.test` will refer to the jQuery object wrapped around my list so I would have thought that `this.myMethod = function() {` would have worked but it doesn't. `$(this)` would be a double wrapper, `el` is my list (and I don't want to assign the method directly to the object since I wouldn't be able to call it like this: `$('#list').whiten()`), and `$(el)` would be the same as `$(this)`... so how is this done?

**-- update --**

I've created a [[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KW9v6/)] to play with the problem

**-- update --**

I also did try placing the method in the `$.fn.test` function but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $.fn.test = function(options) {        
   options = $.extend(options, $.test.settings);      
   var self = this;  
   return this.each(function() {
        $.test(self, options);
    });
};
```

Comment: @Mrcheif, it didn't help.  see the jsfiddle I added

Comment: I'm getting `$("#list").whiten is not a function` on click.

Comment: yes, that the problem I have.  I don't quite know how to make the method assignment

Answer (score 0):

after much wailing and gnashing of teeth, I figured it out.  I'm not sure I understand why it works that way but for now I'm just happy it does!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://goo.gl/XQPhA"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $.test = {
        bg: 'white'
    };

    $.fn.test = function(options) {
        options = $.extend({}, $.test, options);

        this.whiten = function() {
            $(this).css('background-color', options.bg);
        };

        return this.each(function() {
            $.fn.test(options);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#list').test().css('background-color', 'wheat');
    $('#go').click(function() {
        $('#list').whiten();
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<button id="go">whiten</button>
<ul id="list">
<li>Aloe</li>
<li>Bergamot</li>
<li>Calendula</li>
<li>Damiana</li>
<li>Elderflower</li>
<li>Feverfew</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should take a look at the [jQueryUI Widget Factory](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget-factory). jQuery plugins were never the same after I started using that!