# plugin methods - what's the magic here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I struggled and finally got [[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591247/plugin-method-declarations-cant-make-it-work)] to work.  now, I wanted to break it up as shown below but it doesn't work... is there some voodoo here I don't understand?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://goo.gl/XQPhA"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $.test = function(options) {
        options = $.extend({}, $.test.settings, options);

        this.whiten = function() {
            $(this).css('background-color', options.bg);
        };
    };
    $.test.settings = { bg: 'white' };

    $.fn.test = function(options) {
        return this.each(function(index, el) {
            $.test(options);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul').test().css('background-color', 'wheat');
    $('#go').click(function() {
        $('ul').whiten();
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<button id="go">whiten</button>
<ul id="list1">
<li>Aloe</li>
<li>Bergamot</li>
<li>Calendula</li>
<li>Damiana</li>
<li>Elderflower</li>
<li>Feverfew</li>
</ul>
<ul id="list2">
<li>Ginger</li>
<li>Hops</li>
<li>Iris</li>
<li>Juniper</li>
<li>Kavakava</li>
<li>Lavender</li>
<li>Marjoram</li>
<li>Nutmeg</li>
<li>Oregano</li>
<li>Pennroyal</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

as compared with the previous code, inside of the `each()` loop I call now `$.test(options)` instead of `$.fn.test(options)` - so why does one work and not the other (actually, why/how does the first one work to begin with)?

Comment: I'm confused as to why you don't just define test as a function within $.fn.test and keep the standardised jQuery style (which is in place so you don't touch any other namespaces) - http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: @djlumley, you mean like in my previous question? because there's value in being able to do $.test(...)

Comment: As far as I'm aware. $ is literally the jQuery object (once passed with $) and $.fn is the jQuery prototype allowing you to extend methods and therefore allowing you to call $('object').method, so if for any reason you want to be able to call a method using that syntax, it needs to extend the prototype using $.fn.method_name = function()

Comment: @djlumley, I guess what I don't really understand is why/how my first case works

Answer (score 2):

I would restructure your plugin to follow the guidelines outlined in the [plugin authoring guide](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring), most notably storing the data for the settings for your widget with `.data()` and making method calls to your plugin with `.test("method")`:

```
(function($) {
    /* Default plugin settings: */
    var settings = {
        bg: 'white'
    };

    /* Method definitions: */
    var methods = {
        init: function(options) {
            options = $.extend({}, options, settings);
            return this.each(function () {
                $(this).data("test", options);
            });
        },
        whiten: function() {
            var options = this.data("test");
            this.css('background-color', options.bg);
        }
    };

    /* Plugin definition and method calling logic: */
    $.fn.test = function(method) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist');
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Usage: `$("elem").test()`, `$("elem").test("whiten")`

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/z4R3X/

An additional resource for plugin authoring guidance is the jQueryUI source code (take the [autocomplete widget](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js) for example). These widgets are pretty good examples of how to create reusable, readable jQuery plugins.

Comment: I'm aware of that interface but I feel that coding $('whatever').myMethod() is more natural than $('whatever').myPlugin('myMethod')

Comment: @ekkis: If that's the case, just call the plugin `whiten` and pass the appropriate settings object. Calling `$("selector").myMethod()` may seem more natural but the majority of the major plugins out there are using jQuery's recommended pattern. Think about maintaining code that uses your plugin over a large JS code base. Is initializing the plugin and then tens of lines later calling a method on it really more intuitive then always referencing the plugin name when calling a method?